# Tenses in adverbial clauses of time

Tags: subordinate-clauses

There's a rule saying that in adverbial clauses of time we use a present tense to refer to the future. Is *I shall go home after the goods are examined.* correct? What's the difference between *I shall go home after the goods are examined* and *I shall go home after the goods have been examined*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning. They mean exactly the same thing.

Which construction people choose often depends on the context.

So while **I leave tomorrow** and **I will leave tomorrow** convey exactly the same information, the first construction might be used simply to inform someone and the second to emphasise the speaker's determination.

The same is frequently true for the choice between the present tense and the present perfect. In your examples, no such distinction of nuance or intention is obvious.